# Change image DPI to 300 dpi

Tags: c#

```
Bitmap pic;
if (Istopaste)
   pic = new Bitmap((Image)Clipboard.GetImage());
else
   pic = new Bitmap((Image)Clipboard.GetData("bmp"));


    pic.SetResolution(300, 300);
```

But the image still have 96 dpi. How can change image dpi to 300?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  DPI (or PPI) is used to tell the printer what size the image should be when printing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch or this one 
http://www.rideau-info.com/photos/mythdpi.html

Comment: If you have an image with 300x300 pixels of size and print it to a paper sheet with a printer with 300 dpi (dots (~pixels) per inch), the image on the paper would be 1x1 inches.

Comment: and how did you check the image's DPI?

Comment: in image property, horizontal and vertical resolution...

Comment: Did you save the pic?

Comment: Also consider using `300.0F` rather than 300

Comment: i have used like this  using (Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)img.Bitmap())
                                    {
                                        using (Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap))
                                        {
                                            newBitmap.SetResolution(300, 300);
                                            newBitmap.Save(jpegImage, ImageFormat.Tiff);                                       

                                        }
                                    }

Comment: so now i am able to see the image with 300 dpi